# How to synchronize to a NTP server on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, ntp

My Windows XP doesn't have the synchronization tab under Control Panel > Date and Time settings. I tried to change the related registry settings, and it worked only for my Windows 7. What else should I try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Make sure the *Windows Time* (`w32time`) service is running. (Either through `services.msc`, or `sc query w32time` and `sc start w32time`.)
- Try running `w32tm /register` as an administrator.
- Try manual configuration: `w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:pool.ntp.org /update`
- ...and manual resync: `w32tm /resync`
- Also open `eventvwr.msc` and check the Application and System logs for errors.

Comment: I didn't work before for 2 reasons: 1) the pool.ntp.org site was redirected by the corporate proxy to nowhere and 2) the updated time didn't show until I changed the time manually

Comment: @Jader: You didn't mention you are on a corporate network. If your computer is part of an Active Directory domain, it has been already syncing to the domain controller. (If the time difference between DC's and workstation's clocks is too big, domain authentication will not work. Besides, when workstations sync to the controller, there is only one place for the admin to configure.)

Comment: I suspect the AD is unsynchronized with the rest of the world. So I had to make a workaround.

Comment: @Jader: That might be the case, but it's possible that your "workaround" might break domain logins for you. IIRC, the Kerberos protocol can tolerate up to +-5 minutes in the default configuration, but be careful anyway - and ask the domain admin to fix clocks.

Comment: It worked like a charm for me, thanks! And I have to add that I use: 1.us.pool.ntp.org as a server, if it is any help.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note for anyone who comes across this solution in the future -- if the command above doesn't work, add `/syncfromflags:manual` in there as well like this:

`w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual /update`